# Pass pointer to structure

Tags: c++

i am used to code in ASM and had the need to switch to C++ for some OpenGL project. Anyway i got the following procedure:

```
glGenBuffers(Size, PointerToBuff);
```

According to what i understand the handles according to the Size argument (Number of buffers) will be stored on PointerToBuff. So i wanted to use an structure to save the 2 handles i will get in case i use:

```
glGenBuffers(2, *PointerToBuff);
```

So i create an struct:

```
struct VertexHandlers
{
    GLuint cubevertex;
    GLuint trianglevertex;
}VBHandlers;
```

And use the proc as this:

```
glGenBuffers(2, &VBHandlers);
```

The error i get its:

```
error C2664: 'void (GLsizei,GLuint *)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'main::VertexHandlers *' to 'GLuint *'
2>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
2>C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\Downloads\OpenGL-tutorial_v0003\playground\playground.cpp(181): error C2664: 'void (GLsizei,GLuint *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'main::VertexHandlers *' to 'GLsizei'
2>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

I am not used to "Typecast" barely know something, but when regarding pointers i tought (&) operator will take addr of the local variable created. Hope i get some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glGenBuffers()` expects an array of `GLuint`s, not a pointer to an object that happens to have two `GLuint`s in a row. That's why the compiler complains about it. Yes, they both may have the same memory representation on your machine, but it may not be the case on another.

If you want to store the results of `glGenBuffers()` into a structure, you can do something like this:

```
GLuint buffers[2];
glGenBuffers(2, buffers);
VBHandlers.cubevertex = buffers[0];
VBHandlers.trianglevertex = buffers[1];
```

This is the safest, portable way to do it, assuming `glGenBuffers` doesn't fail.

Comment: Thx it worked too, but when you mean memory representation i dont get it. A pointer to an local struct that happens to have 8 bytes (2 Gluints or 2 dwords) its the same as a pointer to an local array that have 8 bytes. So when you meaning memory representation i dont get it much. Anyway the procedure works in both answers provide, thx much.

Comment: @user1175832: Again, it may be the case that an array of two `GLuint`s have the exact same layout as a `struct` with two `GLuint`s in a row, *on your particular compiler and/or machine*. Other compilers and machines may not do it the same way. It's implementation specific.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error is telling you that you are passing the wrong type into the function. It is expecting a pointer to GLuint wher eyou are tyring to give it a pointer to a VertexHandler. If the types are the exact same representation in memory you can cast the parameter by using `glGenBuffers(2, (GLuint*) &VBHandlers);` However this is likely to crash because the types are probably different representations in memory.

Comment: Really you should be defining the values in the format they are expected in. If glGenBuffers is expecting an array of 2 GLuint's pass that. Casting the struct will work in some situations but only by luck (and or deep understanding of the compiler being used). On top of that, if someone were to modify your struct by adding a field between those values, it would break your casting operation. You really should avoid using that cast even if it works in this case. In Silico's solution would be the correct way of doing the solution.